# How do I make a small handheld from scratch that I can put a simple homemade game onto?

Tags: arduino

Alright, some how I couldn't find really anything about this on the internet so far, but I'm trying to find a way to make my own small simple handheld device with a small screen from scratch and then find a way to program a very simple game onto it. Kind of like those small handhelds that were at McDonald's that just had a few buttons, and the game was very simple to play. Anything will help, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The Meggy Jr. is an open source hardware kit to make a GameBoy like device with an LED matrix screen.

http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/meggy-jr-rgb/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fisrt step would be to separate the "handheld" into smaller units that will be more or less independent and then research each unit by itself and finally see how you can integrate them into a whole.

Such a project would (using technologies popular today) need a microcontroller plus programming hardware, some type of display unit, some sort of user input system, some sort of audio system, power supply and battery management system and a case in which you'll fit all of that.

For each of these subsystems, you'll need to determine how complex you want it to be. The complexity level you can reach mostly depends on how much electronics knowledge you have and how much time you want to dedicate to this project. Since there are many books written about each of the points, I'll just try to provide an overview of what you can use and what to research.

As far as displays are concerned, you have various types of LED displays, like in the unit Toby posted, and another option would be graphical (or maybe even character only) LCD screens. As far as the screens are concerned, you have two basic types: One that use some sort of serial protocol such as I^2C or SPI and ones that have large number of pins and are sometimes called parallel. Basically the serial ones are a bit smarter and a bit more expensive, but they take up less pins of  your microcontroller, which can be a plus point. The parallel type is a bit cheaper and has more control inputs which eat up pins on microcontroller. You can sole that using various types of I/O expansion systems, such as series of shift registers, decoders or demultiplexers. The LED screens usually have LEDs line up in a matrix, such as on this monochrome 5x7 display:
[image]

You basically need to source current on some lines and sink on others in order to enable a single dot. By enabling a number of dots, you can form an image. Color versions of screens such as this one have in each dot 3 diodes, so you can mix colors. The downside is that you'll really have to use either a specialized LED screen driver chip (and these can be a bit expensive) or shift registers and current sinks and sources.

Next, you have the input system. Here you have the usual pushbutons of various kinds, n-position switches, small joysticks, trackballs, trackpads, touchscreens, tilt sensors, accelerometers, pressure sensors and so on. In general, the pushbuttons and switches are simplest to use and may be fine to navigate through some menus. They're also the cheapest. Joysticks are a bit more complex, since you'd have to do analog to digital conversion, but it's still pretty simple. The main problem with touchscreens is that you'll have to synchronize the screen display and the location of input, but that too isn't too complex. Also you'll need a screen with the touch panel on it. Accelerometers and various kinds of tilt sensors can determine the position of the hand-held unit so it can respond to movement.

For the audio system, you could have the microcontroller play various kinds of noises, say square waves of some or produce beeps and similar. I don't have too much experience in this area, but you can get some information by reading about PC speaker music. Depending on the sound quality you want, you could even get a dedicated analog to digital converter plus audio amplifier and use that to drive a speaker.

Next, we have the power. The simplest way to power everything would be to choose such components that can work on voltage range from say 3.3 V to 5 V and then use 3 non-rechargeable AA batteries for power. When they're full, they'll provide 4.5 V and over time you'll get lower and lower voltage. At around 3 V, the system would stop working. If you can't get everything working at 5 V, you could use a 3.3 V system plus a low dropout regulator and power everything from 4 AA cells.  A more complex solution would use a rechargeable battery system with some sort of low voltage cut-off. This way, NiMH or even LiPO cells could be used. Today there are many one chip battery charging solutions, so you could go that way too and integrate a battery into the hand-held unit.

Near the end, I'll mention the microcontroller which can be used to provide the "heart" of the whole unit. Today most popular ones seem to be Microchip's PIC line and Atmel's AVR line. For a simple game, you could easily use a microcontroller from PIC16 or PIC 18 Series or an AVR ATmega series microcontroller. Exact unit will depend on how complex the rest of the system is and how complex the game you want to have. Another interesting platform could be the Parallax Propeller. Unlike the PICs and AVRs, it has 8 core processor, so you can do more things at the same time and more smoothly compared to PICs and AVRs. The downside of it is that it's a 3.3 V only unit, so you can't use the simplest option of having 3 AA cells for power supply.

Finally, you have the case and the PCB. Depending on how complex you want to go, you could use a simple one side PCB which you could make at home (or use some of the more permanent prototyping boards such as stripboard) or you could get a professional two or more layer PCB. Since it's expensive to order a single PCB, there are services on the Internet that pool together people who need small number of PCBs and them send them all together to be made. Using them, you could save some money.

The enclosure itself will require some thought and it will mostly be the product of previous design choices. You'll of course need holes for whatever input system you decide to use, a transparent part for the screen, access to the battery holder and so on. I don't have much experience in this area, so I won't comment on how difficult it will be to make a good quality enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

I would go and purchase a ARM Cortex M3/4 type board, reasonably powerful but still low cost. They come with buttons LCDs etc.

Once I am comfortable with the environment, I would put an emulator of an old 8bit game machine to make the device available to various games. This may require you to license the games however you would also find a slew of games developed by independent developers that require no royalty.